# Error while loading pvr.ccz textures in iOS

Tags: ios, textures, pvrtc

I'm using TexturePacker to create my sprite sheets for my iOS game. Everything is working fine with generated PNG textures (RGBA 4444), the textures are correctly loaded inside my code and correctly displayed on the iPad screen but as soon I remplace those textures by the PVRC format (pvr.ccz) with PVRTCI 4bpp RGBA pixel format, I get the following message for each of my textures from the console:

"SKTexture: Error loading image resource: "/var/containers/Bundle/Application/657D8692-594C-4180-AA8B-6CE35962C8D5/FurryLight Puzzles.app/Puzzle0.atlasc/Puzzle0.2.pvr.ccz"

The textures generated by TexturePacker are all POT and SQUARE format (2048x2048 max), the plist files are inside my directories .atlasc with the pvr.ccz files. In fact, I just replace the precedent .atlasc directories inside my tree shader inside Xcode with the PNG files by the new .atlasc directories with pvr.ccz files. All my code is in Swift 3.0

What am I missing, is there something to tune somewhere ? The pvr.ccz textures are correctly displayed by Xcode when I click on them inside the tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the reply I got from the creators of TexturePacker:

"I am currently not sure if pvr works - you can try it. But pvr.ccz surely does not work.
pvr.ccz is a special format for cocos2d(x). It compresses the pvr files with zlib. This is not supported by SpriteKit.
Best
Andreas
"